# Buffer Overflow - Format String Vulnerability and Exploit

Tags: gdb, cpu-architecture, buffer-overflow, security

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyGDezTO4aM&list=PLAqsm_Kdol5hicboCpGvHTeoqGA-K30Zm&index=3) on YouTube to learn about Buffer Overflow exploits. The main difference I can see between his machine and mine is that his addresses consist of 8-bytes and mine consist of 12. However, both of our memory blocks appear to be 8-bytes.

When he runs his exploit command inside of gdb, he uses
`r $(python -c 'print "\xff\xff\xff\xff" + "%08x-" * 6 + "%s"')`
where `"\xff\xff\xff\xff"` is his memory address.

I run my command using
`r $(python -c 'print "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF" + "%08x-" * 3 + "%s"')`
where `\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF` is my memory address. (I changed his `*6` to `*3` as his stack pointer was 6 away from his memory address and mine was 3 away).

I have tried changing the number of `"%08x"` values I have present as well as changing the value to `%x012` as well as `%x12`.

Is there a specific way of dealing with 12-byte addresses, or is this exploit present with 12-byte addresses? ASLS is disabled.

Comment: Do you mean 12 hex digits?  That's 6 bytes, 48-bit.  Probably actually 64-bit, but with high zeros, like normal for x86-64 canonical addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you compiled your program as 64bit, while the teacher did his in 32bit.

The buffer overflow won't work the same in a 64bit mode. There are different things to consider. Recommend compiling as 32bit and trying that way if you want to get the basics down first.

Comment: I'll do that and might I'll come back to it in the future in 64-bit. What would be the main considerations when converting to 64 bit?